# List of images to point cloud in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cloud, point, printer-control-language

Could anybody suggest an automatic way to convert from a list of images (without Kinect) to a point cloud in opencv?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at OpenCV Contrib [Structure From Motion module (SFM)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/sfm). There are two nice examples `trajectory_reconstruction.cpp` and `scene_reconstruction.cpp`.

Also, there is alternative called [Multi-View Environment](http://www.gcc.tu-darmstadt.de/home/proj/mve/) which you could find on [GitHub at simonfuhrmann/mve](https://github.com/simonfuhrmann/mve) and which might meet your criteria too.